# Is it required to free pointers in C when using default gcc compiler in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

If the dynamically allocated pointers are not freed in C when using the default gcc compiler in linux, will it cause problems in system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a memory leak, and if you keep doing it, you'll run out of memory (triggering the OOM-killer). But it won't leak memory beyond the lifetime of your program if that's what you're asking; all allocated memory is returned to the OS automatically when the process exits.

Comment: That answered my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @HARDY8118: If it solved your problem, please click the check mark next to this answer to indicate the problem is solved.